# Simple way to gather information from model output

Tags: r, function, dplyr, functional-programming, mclust

Consider this data frame:

```r
set.seed(123)
dat1 <- data.frame(Region = rep(c("r1","r2"), each = 100),
                   State = rep(c("NY","MA","FL","GA"), each = 10),
                   Loc = rep(c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"),each = 5),
                   ID = rep(c(1:10), each = 2),
                   var1 = rnorm(200),
                   var2 = rnorm(200),
                   var3 = rnorm(200),
                   var4 = rnorm(200),
                   var5 = rnorm(200),
                   var6 = rnorm(200))
dat1$ID <- factor(dat1$ID)
```

I am using the mclust package to fit a mixture model and get bootstrapped standard errors as shown here:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(mclust)
set.seed(123)
mod <- Mclust(dat1[,5:10], G=5, modelNames = "VEI", initialization = list(hcPairs = randomPairs(dat1[,5:10], seed = 123)))
plot(mod, what = "classification")
plot(mod, what = "density")
boot <- MclustBootstrap(mod, nboot = 25, type = "bs")#25 for now to speed up
```

Next I want to create a new data frame that shows the mixture probabilities for each observation, so I combine the original `dat1` with `mod$z`.

```r
probs <- mod$z
colnames(probs) <- paste0("Prob", 1:mod$G)
probs <- cbind(dat1, probs)
probs <- cbind(probs, cluster = mod$classification)
```

Now I want collect:
1) the average value of each variable within each cluster, and 2) the standard error for each of those averages (which comes from `summary(boot, what = "SE")$mean`). I will use these to create the plot below, and return a table that shows the average and SE values.

```r
newdat <- cbind(dat1, cluster = mod$classification)
a <-
  newdat%>%
  dplyr::select_if(is.numeric)%>%
  dplyr::group_by(cluster)%>%
  summarise_all(mean)%>%
  pivot_longer(-c("cluster"), names_to = "Vars", values_to = "mean")
b<-
as.data.frame(cbind(cluster=1:mod$G, t(summary(boot, what = "se")$mean)))%>%
   pivot_longer(., -c("cluster"), names_to = "Vars", values_to = "SE")
a<-dplyr::mutate(a, "SE" = b$SE)

ggplot(a, aes(x=Vars, y=mean, group=factor(cluster))) + 
  geom_line(aes(colour=factor(cluster)))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-SE, ymax=mean+SE), width = .1)+
  ggtitle("Mean by cluster") +
    expand_limits(y=0) +                        
    scale_y_continuous(breaks=0:20*4) +         
    labs(x = "Var", y = "Cluster Average")+
    theme_bw() +
    theme(legend.justification=c(1,0),
          legend.position=c(1,0))
library(knitr)
kable(a)
```

Ultimately I want to write a function that will perform each of these steps and return the output at once. It will be applied to data frames structured just like `dat1`, except they will have different numbers of `var` columns. I will also need to specify how many clusters to use and which model to use when `mod` is created. What is a better way for me to collect the information that is stored in `a` so that the same process can be applied to any combination of variables (`var.` columns) and mixture components (`G` specified in `mod`) from within a function?

Comment: Have you looked at the broom and tidymodels packages? I'm not totally clear on what you want to do / what part of the code needs to change, but those might help

Comment: @camille I tried to provide the background of what I was doing and why, but maybe this makes my specific question less obvious. I will attempt to clarify. My question here concerns methods of extracting the means and standard errors from the objects `mod` and `boot` (the creation of object `a`). I essentially need a different way to create `a` without creating `b` because the matrix transposition used to create `b` is problematic with some combinations of variables and mixture components.

Comment: FYI the tidymodels package may be a good route. I used `a<- data.frame(cbind(tidy(mod), t(summary(boot, what = "se")$mean)))` to get the information I need, now I just need to get it in the same format as `a` above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can do something along these lines:

```r
set.seed(123)
dat1 <- data.frame(Region = rep(c("r1","r2"), each = 100),
                   State = rep(c("NY","MA","FL","GA"), each = 10),
                   Loc = rep(c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"),each = 5),
                   ID = rep(c(1:10), each = 2),
                   var1 = rnorm(200),
                   var2 = rnorm(200),
                   var3 = rnorm(200),
                   var4 = rnorm(200),
                   var5 = rnorm(200),
                   var6 = rnorm(200))
dat1$ID <- factor(dat1$ID)
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
library(mclust)
#> Package 'mclust' version 5.4.6
#> Type 'citation("mclust")' for citing this R package in publications.

clusterVars <- function(dat, col_idx, G=5, seed=123){
    mod <- Mclust(dat[, col_idx], G=G, modelNames = "VEI", 
        initialization = list(hcPairs = randomPairs(dat[, col_idx], seed = seed)))
    plot(mod, what = "classification")
    plot(mod, what = "density")
    boot <- MclustBootstrap(mod, nboot = 25, type = "bs")#25 for now to speed up
    mydat <- data.table(dat, mod$z, cluster = mod$classification)
    setnames(mydat, old= paste0("V", seq_len(G)), new=paste0("Prob", seq_len(G)))
    a <- mydat[,(mean = lapply(.SD, mean)), by = c("cluster"), 
                .SDcols=colnames(dat)[col_idx]]
    a <- setkey(melt(
        a, id.vars = "cluster", variable.name = "Vars", value.name = "mean"), 
        cluster, Vars)
    b <- setkey(melt(
        data.table(cluster = seq_len(G), t(summary(boot, what = "se")$mean)), 
        id.vars = "cluster", variable.name = "Vars", value.name = "SE"),
        cluster, Vars)
    out <- a[b]
    p <- ggplot(out, aes(x=Vars, y=mean, group=factor(cluster))) + 
        geom_line(aes(colour=factor(cluster)))+
        geom_point()+
        geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-SE, ymax=mean+SE), width = .1)+
        ggtitle("Mean by cluster") +
        expand_limits(y=0) +                        
        scale_y_continuous(breaks=0:20*4) +         
        labs(x = "Var", y = "Cluster Average")+
        theme_bw() +
        theme(legend.justification=c(1,0),
              legend.position=c(1,0))
    list(plot = p, table = out)       
}

out <- clusterVars(dat1, col_idx = 5:10, G = 5)
```

[image][image]

```r
plot(out$plot)
```

[image]

```r
out$table
#>     cluster Vars         mean        SE
#>  1:       1 var1 -0.239846636 0.2286331
#>  2:       1 var2  0.496303497 0.4237945
#>  3:       1 var3  0.045489269 0.2392820
#>  4:       1 var4  0.035899698 0.3157938
#>  5:       1 var5  0.852212286 0.4683157
#>  6:       1 var6 -0.652884807 0.3000536
#>  7:       2 var1 -0.177353942 0.4626206
#>  8:       2 var2 -0.155370426 0.4879140
#>  9:       2 var3  0.760466010 0.4773900
#> 10:       2 var4  0.000245426 0.5210745
#> 11:       2 var5 -0.534355806 0.3960204
#> 12:       2 var6  0.023759375 0.3364228
#> 13:       3 var1  2.308773892 0.7389746
#> 14:       3 var2 -0.095760375 0.6652415
#> 15:       3 var3  1.538477219 0.6248455
#> 16:       3 var4  0.423748712 0.9034914
#> 17:       3 var5  0.526404192 0.4475889
#> 18:       3 var6  0.147645599 0.4308516
#> 19:       4 var1  0.223028905 0.5078972
#> 20:       4 var2 -0.028866278 0.2597171
#> 21:       4 var3 -1.005246422 0.5143203
#> 22:       4 var4 -0.084080497 0.5511872
#> 23:       4 var5 -0.194968718 0.3312450
#> 24:       4 var6  0.255504356 0.3616244
#> 25:       5 var1  0.023540106 0.4559344
#> 26:       5 var2 -0.572302120 0.5058384
#> 27:       5 var3  0.782263291 0.3809646
#> 28:       5 var4 -0.202702860 0.3913615
#> 29:       5 var5  0.061927990 1.0652221
#> 30:       5 var6  2.019626078 0.5999117
#>     cluster Vars         mean        SE
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>